# window.location.href is not working on Internet Explorer browser?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, internet-explorer

I am writing a JavaScript code on click of a hyperlink using  ng-click="method()" attribute on the anchor tag  as below -

```
 <a href="" ng-click="method()">
    <span>Get Started !! </span>
 </a>
```

Inside method(), I am redirecting to another URL based on some condition as below

```
service.activateUser($scope.patientId, $scope.activationCode).then(function (status) {
                            var endIndex = window.location.href.lastIndexOf("currentPage");
                            var nextPage={};

                            //For digital type patients, redirect to page1
                            if ($scope.patientType == 1) {
                                nextPage = window.location.href.substring(0, endIndex) + "page1";
                            }
                            //For analog type patients, redirect to page2
                            else {
                                nextPage = window.location.href.substring(0, endIndex) + "page2";
                            }

                            window.location.href = nextPage;
                        })
```

However, in Internet explorer, its throwing exception as "unhandled exception $rootscope.infdig".

Comment: You are using angular so try $location.path(yourpath);

Comment: [Looking at the docs for that error](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$rootScope/infdig) suggests that it's caused by an infinite series of `$digest` cycles. Is there any other helpful information that's getting displayed in the console?

Answer (score 1):

I added a try catch block to surround my code and it worked :) :)